# Merging two dataframes using right join does not give me the desired output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, right-join

I have two dataframes; `df1` and `df2`

`df1` looks like this:

[image]

`df2` looks like this:

[image]

My aim is to join `df1` and `df2` based on three keys:  `city`, `Year` and `Asset_Type`  as follows:

```
Index_step1=pd.merge( df1, df2[['city','Year','Asset_Type','psqm_city','city_returns']] , right_on =['city','Year', 'Asset_Type'], left_on=['city','Year','Asset_Type'], how = 'right')
```

My aim is to have the values of the Year `2021` appear in the output `Index_step1` (`2021` appear in `df2` but not in `df1`). The `right_join` should keep the rows of the right dataframe (`df2`) but i am puzzled as to why the values of the `Year` `2021` do not appear in the output which looks like this (see below). I also tried outer join but the values of `Year` `2021` still do not appear there. Any idea what i am missing here? Thanks

```
Index_step1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah looks like a bug and I'm gonna recommend a weird thing can you try to write left_on paramater first then right_on cause it seems like your function is doing left join not right join

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is still not working... outer join should work as well (it worked in other places)